# How can I get this grill mesh to fit in this empty space?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap, curve-modifier

How could I get this active object to fill in the annotated empty space? I've tried seperating and edge from the empty space and using the curve modifier as well as filling in the empty space with a new face and then shrinkwrapping but they did not give the desired effects:

[image]

[image: Reference]

Answer (score 0):

You can use mesh boolean modifier:

1. Separate edge of empty space and make it another object (`P` in edit mode)
2. Fill that edge loop (`F`)
3. Extrude it along normal (`Alt-E`)
4. Select other face and move it along normal for same amount in opposite direction (select face, ``` ,``2 ```, ``` G``Z ```)
5. Hide created object (`H`)
6. Place your grill on empty space, rotate as you like it to be
7. Add a boolean modifier to grill, set mode to Intersection, select your hidden object